# Oracle SQL sum is returning duplicate rows?

Tags: oracle

Stupid question but ...

Im trying to sum all of the sd_stock but it is giving me multiple rows instead of a single row.

Example
There are two rows in the database

```
480245  17312-001026    4   1
480245  17312-001026    1   1
```

the SQL

```
  SELECT
  SD_STOCK,
  sum( SD_QTY_ORDER) SD_QTY_ORDER
  from SD
  where
  SD_STOCK like '17312-001026'
  and SD_STATUS in ( '1', '2')
  and trim(sd_order) in
  (
     '480245'
  )
  group by  (SD_STOCK,sd_qty_order)
```

I get the following

```
17312-001026    1
17312-001026    4
```

I know im doing it wrong but i cant figure out what.  Can you help?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to `group by  (SD_STOCK,sd_qty_order)` ? Why not simply `group by  (SD_STOCK)` ?

Comment: This would work if the sd_qty_order was 4, or 1 on both records. :P

Comment: Damn!  that fixed it

Comment: Is it clear to you _why_ it fixed your issue?

Comment: Because i hadgroup by  (SD_STOCK,sd_qty_order) instead of group by  SD_STOCK